# jqPlot data in same series sit on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I have a small issue with a jqplot chart im trying to create.

I want to put all 2008 data into one category and style it with a certain colour, then do the same for 2009.

Currently I have this output:

[how current chart looks (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP2G2.jpg)

Using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // For horizontal bar charts, x an y values must will be "flipped"
    // from their vertical bar counterpart.
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('tableTest', [
        [[10,2008], [12,2008], [11,2008], [13,2008]],
        [[2,2009], [4,2009], [6,2009], [3,2009],]
        ], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
            // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
            // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they
            // will be hidden.
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
            // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
            shadowAngle: 135,
            // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,

                /*rendererOptions: {
                    groupLabels:['Fruits', 'Vegetables']
                }*/

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can seperate out the bars?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add your own custom ticks, and format the data slightly differently. I've made the adjustments to the code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpp39/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // For horizontal bar charts, x an y values must will be "flipped"
    // from their vertical bar counterpart.

    var ticks = ['2008', '2009'];

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('tableTest', [[10, 2], [12, 3], [11, 6], [13, 3]], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
            // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
            // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they
            // will be hidden.
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
            // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
            shadowAngle: 135,
            // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is good but not exactly what im looking to do (unfortunatly I asked the question wrong above). Here the first series is set to the axis label '2008'. Im looking for sub ticks, so; series one data [10], [12], [11] ect is marked '2008' '2009' '2010' ect whilst still staying in a seies together. Like this: [plot example](http://imgur.com/5eotl) 

Im sorry this is different from my origional question

Comment: @blacktea is this what you mean [http://jsfiddle.net/tpp39/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/tpp39/3/)

Comment: Not quite: more like this [plot example] (http://imgur.com/5eotl).

Although I've come up with a solution its not ideal. I pass in the data as a single array item and pass a list of ticks for each bar. This means there is only a single series, limiting my options for colouring the bar.

thank you for your help, if you can think of a better solution then please let me know